# Calculator code not working, gives wrong answer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a calculator code to evaluate addition, subtraction, and squares. For example, the expression "1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;" should evaluate to 1012. For some reason my code gives me the wrong answer :( It evaluates to 63. Where does the issue occur in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int answer = 0, num;
    char sign;
    cin >> num; 

    while (cin >> sign)
    {
        if (sign == '^')
        {
            answer += num * num;
            cin >> sign >> num;
            
            if (sign == '+')
            {
                answer += num;
            }
            else if (sign == '-')
            {
                answer -= num;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (sign == '+')
            {
                cin >> num;
                answer += num;
            }
            else if (sign == '-')
            {
                cin >> num;
                answer -= num;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << answer << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start simple.  Enter `1+1` and verify that is correct.  Then move to subtraction, multiplication and so on.  You will find the bug quickly.

Comment: This home-grown solution is never going to work, because you are completely ignoring operator precedence. Look up recursive descent expression parsing, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a **step-by-step** approach. Taking the input as `1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;`, which is actually `1000<spacebar>+<spacebar>6^<spacebar>-<spacebar>5^<spacebar>+<spacebar>1;`

1. Firstly, after you take `1000` as `num`, `<spacebar>` follow as a `sign`. As `<spacebar>` does not match any of the `sign`, this `1000` is **discarded** because it does not hit any of the `if` case.
2. Then, `+` is took as a `sign`, making `<spacebar>6 -> 6` as `num`,  so `num` becomes the `6`, then added to the `answer`. Making it to `6`. Then, `^` is encountered. That adds `36` to the `answer`, making the `answer` to `42`.
3. Then again `<spacebar>` is encountered, making the `answer` untouched. Then, `-` `sign` is encountered. reading `<spacebar>5 -> 5` as `num`, it will subtract `5` from `42`, making the `answer` `37`.
4. Next, `^` will be encountered, adding `25` to the `answer`, the `answer` will be `62`.
5. Then, `<spacebar>` is again encountered as a `sign`, having no effect to the `answer`.
6. Lastly, `+` will be encountered, adding `<spacebar>1 -> 1` to the `answer`, Therefore, the final `answer` will be `63` for this expression. Additional `;` will be treated as a `sign` with no matches, therefore will not affect the final `answer`.

As you see, because of the `<spacebar>` and the fact that `cin >> <char>` only takes exactly 1 character as the input, and also accepts the **white-space characters**, you get **unexpected result**.

**Remember**: **Computer** exactly **does** what **you programmed**, **not** what **you** actually **intended**.

If you want to parse the mathematical expression correctly, study about

Shunting-yard algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

And Postfix notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Those two algorithms are extensively used when the real-world calculator is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but this type of problem (calculator) requires usage of stack, because there are many things to consider like operator precedence. For example, if there is a bracket then expression within brackets should be solved first. So, I advise to look in this further as there will be many good article explaining this.